# When connecting through mobile broadband from Windows 7 a new network type appears

Tags: windows-7, networking

Whenever I connect through mobile broadband inside my modem in Windows 7, the dialog

> Define Network Type

appears, showing a new network name (which is the carrier) appended with an incremental number. How do I delete the old connections and stop showing the `Define Network Type` for **this** 3G connection only? I searched in registry but no entry matches the network name.

Also, if I run `ipconfig` I receive a lot of disconnected `isatap` entries.

Comment: Tangentially germane: I have hundreds of those entries on one of my test XP rigs but they increment only when I insert a new device, not when I'm inserting a previously installed device.